# Dynamic Column Height in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, calendar, reportbuilder3.0

So I'm trying to make a calendar report in SSRS and was wondering if there was a way to have columns with height that automatically adjusts based on the number of values inside to eliminate white space. For example, in one column there are 4 values and in the column to the right of it there are only 2 values. The column with 2 values has the same height as the one with 4, creating unwanted white space between that column and the one below it--this is not what I want. Thanks in advance!

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to explain:

[image: Calendar Pic]

Comment: Can you give an image of your desired output.  are you trying to display multiple tables of varying heights in the smallest amount of space possible for example?

Comment: Added an image link to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have a number of days, each with a number of events, and each event has a number of items in it.  Have you considered using a matrix to represent the days, and in the data field then having a list of the events for that day.  Inside the list you could then have a table of the values you wish to display.

In the layout below this is a Matrix with the columns grouped by day.  In the data section there is a list (the blue background, that should be grouped on 'Event' in your instance, 'Question' in the example below), and a table (the yellow background)

[image]

When run, the report renders as follows- note the different heights for each yellow table.

[image]

Is this the sort of result you are looking for?  If not please clarify and I’ll see if I can help further

Answer (score 0):

No columns don't have heights, they have widths.

Rows have height and all the columns on the same row have to be the same height, or the result would be unreadable.